# Designing a Turing machine for Binary Division

Tags: binary, turing-machines

I'm trying to design a TM to binary divide 2 numbers. 
The best approach I've found is the method: division  as repeated subtraction, but I don't know if there's a fastest way or an easier way. 
Thanks :)

Comment: I think it is also known as *long division*, and for two general numbers it is the fastest method (in fact, it's probably the **only** method).

Comment: You need to have some limitations, since the division implementation  might be operation that does not provide a result even after infinite time, and it could happen as you start the machine...